# Exp:resso Store & PayPal Advanced

Tags: expresso-store, paypal

PayPal has several tiers of **on-site** services listed on their business page. One is "Advanced" and the other is Pro. Does Exp:resso Store play nice with Advanced as well as it does Pro?

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed. Paypal seems to re-name and re-define it's offerings a lot but at present it boils down to

- Website Payments Standard
- Website Payments Pro
- Paypal Express

Website Payments Standard seems to be deprecated as they introduce the new Express Checkout and as such support for this gateway has been removed from Store by standard.

Website Payments Pro and Paypal Express with both work fine out of the box though with support for both gateways built in.

Comment: Actually, technically I don't think Store supports "Advanced", but from memory PayPal Advanced is functionally identical to PayPal Pro so you should use that instead.

Comment: Proof in point that Paypal are constantly playing with their service offerings. It's hard to keep up. :) I was basing it on [what they list here](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant%2Fproduct_services) and what I was aware of but it seems that there is now a [Paypal Advanced](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advancedhttps://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced). The easiest way is to avoid Paypal altogether. ;)